# iOS 10.3 in-purchases stopped working

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios10.3

after new iOS 10.3 launched, In-Purchases functional stopped working in application suddenly. Actually, this method doesn't call anymore.

```
func requestDidFinish(request: SKRequest) {
  if let receiptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL {
    if let receipt = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptURL) {
      handleReceipt(receipt)
    }
}
```

Seems the connection to AppleStore is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Apple issue, already fixed!